# loop in df with conditionals

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop

I have this function where I would like to change the variables: “preco_ordem” by **df.loc[((df.Ordem ==1), "close")].values** or **df.loc[((df.Ordem ==-1) , "close")].values** and quote for each row value of column **df['close']** . if Order = 1 scroll through the close values until finding a value greater or less than the constraints, or inverse if -1.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

#variaveis
cotacao = 27.62
tp = 0.30
sl = 0.20
preco_ordem = 28.51

list_1 = [26.66, 26.7, 26.72, 26.73, 26.74, 26.88, 26.63, 26.56, 26.51, 26.55, 26.54, 26.5, 26.52, 26.59, 26.43, 26.46, 
          26.54, 26.51, 26.54, 26.5, 26.51, 26.47, 26.48, 26.41, 26.4, 26.37]
list_2 = [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0]

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'close': list_1,
    'Ordem': list_2})

def calcular(preco_ordem, cotacao, tp, sl):
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        #comprado
        if row['Ordem'] == 1:
            #se gain
            if cotacao > (preco_ordem + tp):
                return  (cotacao - preco_ordem)
            #se loss
            if cotacao < (preco_ordem - sl):
                return (cotacao - preco_ordem)
        #vendido    
        if row['Ordem'] == -1:
            #se gain
            if cotacao < (preco_ordem - tp):
                return (preco_ordem - cotacao)
            #se loss
            if cotacao > (preco_ordem + sl):
                return (preco_ordem - cotacao)

calcular(preco_ordem, cotacao, tp, sl)
```

**expected outcome:**

```
list_3 = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -0.2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'close': list_1,
    'Ordem': list_2,
    'resultado': list_3})

df

list_4 = [26.70, 26.51, 26.54]
list_5 = [-0.20, 'Nan', 'Nan']

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'close': list_4,
    'resultado': list_5})
df2
```

Comment: Hi, could you show what the expected result should look like?

Comment: hi, of course I did, I just edited it.